# Organize data with responses to questions in the next row

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have a form data where the information isn’t formatted equally.

The delimiter is `:` but the answer for some are added to the next row.

Example

```
———————————————————————

Subject: form number 123

———————————————————————-


————————————————————————

This is a space for messages

—————————————————————————-


—————————————————————

Age:

—————————-

36

——————————


—————————-

Country:

—————————

CA

—————————-


——————————

Color:

——————————

Red

——————————
```

I would like to have it formatted to have anything before `:` to be a header.

```
Subject  |  Age   |  Country  |  Color
```

How do would I achieve this with google sheet or any free tool out there?

I tried using sublime to format it but still running into the same issue with the answer being in the next row. Is there a way to redirect the answers to have `:` instead of next line/row.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 Hi Thank you. I've updated with desired formatted data and example. i'm not sure if this is what you were requesting. Thanks for the help.